# Open different activities listview item click

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onitemclick

I have a search activity where I have a ListView and i show the title, icon, etc on every single item, and y can search every one.
Actually when i click to one item y open a "blank activity" with a text view, and image view, and it changes with the corresponding title and image.
But now i want to change it and i want to open a specific activity whit every item click.

This is my actual code:

```
public class Buscar extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    int[] crafteo;
    int[] flag;
    int[] actividad;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Generate sample data
        rank = new String[] { "Armaduras", "Armaduras", "Armaduras", "Armaduras", "Armaduras", "Comida", "Comida","Comida",
        "Comida",
        "Comida",
        "Comida",
        "Comida",
        "Comida",
        "Comida",
        "Comida",
        "Comida", "Informativos","Informativos","Informativos","Informativos","Informativos", "Items","Items","Items","Items",
                "Items","Items","Items","Items","Items","Items","Items","Items","Items","Items","Items", "Armas","Armas",
                "Armas","Armas","Armas","Armas","Armas","Vehiculos","Vehiculos","Vehiculos","Vehiculos","Vehiculos",
                "Utilidades","Utilidades","Utilidades","Utilidades","Utilidades","Utilidades","Utilidades","Herramientas",
                "Herramientas","Herramientas","Herramientas","Herramientas","Herramientas","Herramientas","Herramientas",
                "Herramientas","Herramientas","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos",
                "Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos",
                "Mecanismos","Mecanismos","Mecanismos",
        };

        country = new String[] { "Casco", "Peto", "Perneras",
                "Botas", "Armadura Caballo", "Pan", "Pastel",
                "Pollo cocido",
        "Pescado Cocido",
        "Chuleta cerdo C.",
        "Galleta",
        "Manzana Dorada",
        "Zanahoria dorada",
        "Sopa champiñones",
        "Tarta calabaza",
        "Filete",
                "Libro y Pluma",
                "Reloj",
                "Brujula",
                "Mapa",
                "Libro Escrito",

                "Cama",
                "Polvo Llamas",
                "Vara de Llama",
                "Cuenco",
                "Ladrillo",
                "Carbón Vegetal",
                "Ojo de Ender",
                "Lingote de oro",
                "Lingote de hierro",
                "Marco de Objetos",
                "Cuadro",
                "Papel",
                "Palo",
                "Cartel",
                "Antorcha",
                "Espada Diamante",
                "Espada Oro",
                "Espada Hierro",
                "Espada Piedra",
                "Espada Madera",
                "Arco",
                "Flecha",
                "Vagoneta",
                "Vagoneta con Horno",
                "Vagoneta de Mercancias",
                "Bote",
                "Silla de Montar",

                "Mesa de Trabajo",
                "Cofre",
                "Mesa Encantamientos",
                "Valla",
                "Puerta de Valla",
                "Horno",
                "Escalera",

                "Pico",
                "Hacha",
                "Pala",
                "Azada",
                "Cubo",
                "Mechero",
                "Carga Ignea",
                "Frasco de Cristal",
                "Caña de Pescar",
                "Cizallas",

                "Rail Detecetor",
                "Dispensador",
                "Puerta de Hierro",
                "Palanca",
                "Caja de Musica",
                "Piston",
                "Piston Pegajoso",
                "Rail Propulsor",
                "Rail",
                "Lampara de Redstone",
                "Repetidor",
                "Antorcha Redstone",
                "Boton",
                "Placa de Presion",
                "TNT",
                "Puerta",
                "Trampilla",





        };

        population = new String[] { "Normal", "Normal",
                "Normal", "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal","Normal",
                "Normal",};

        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.casco, R.drawable.armadura,
                R.drawable.pernera, R.drawable.botas,
                R.drawable.caballo, R.drawable.pan, R.drawable.pastel,
                R.drawable.polloc,
                R.drawable.pezc,
                R.drawable.ccerdoc,
                R.drawable.galleta,
                R.drawable.manzanad,
                R.drawable.zanahoriad,
                R.drawable.sopac,
                R.drawable.tartac,
                R.drawable.filete,
                R.drawable.libropluma,
                R.drawable.relojc,
                R.drawable.brujula,
                R.drawable.mapa,
                R.drawable.libro,
                R.drawable.cama,
                R.drawable.pllamas,
                R.drawable.vllama,
                R.drawable.cuenco,
                R.drawable.ladrillo,
                R.drawable.carbonv,
                R.drawable.ojoe,
                R.drawable.lingoteo,
                R.drawable.lingoteh,
                R.drawable.marcoo,
                R.drawable.cuadro,
                R.drawable.papel,
                R.drawable.palo,
                R.drawable.cartel,
                R.drawable.antorcha,
                R.drawable.espadad,
                R.drawable.espadao,
                R.drawable.espadah,
                R.drawable.espadap,
                R.drawable.espadam,
                R.drawable.arco,
                R.drawable.flecha,
                R.drawable.vagoneta,
                R.drawable.vagonetah,
                R.drawable.vagonetam,
                R.drawable.bote,
                R.drawable.sillam,
                R.drawable.mtrabajo,
                R.drawable.cofre,
                R.drawable.mencantamientos,
                R.drawable.valla,
                R.drawable.pvalla,
                R.drawable.horno,
                R.drawable.escalera,
                R.drawable.picod,
                R.drawable.hachad,
                R.drawable.palad,
                R.drawable.azadad,
                R.drawable.cubo,
                R.drawable.mechero,
                R.drawable.cignea,
                R.drawable.fcristal,
                R.drawable.cpescar,
                R.drawable.cizallas,
                R.drawable.raild,
                R.drawable.dispensador,
                R.drawable.puertah,
                R.drawable.palanca,
                R.drawable.cajam,
                R.drawable.piston,
                R.drawable.pistonp,
                R.drawable.railp,
                R.drawable.rail,
                R.drawable.lamparar,
                R.drawable.repetidor,
                R.drawable.antorchar,
                R.drawable.boton,
                R.drawable.placap,
                R.drawable.tnt,
                R.drawable.puerta,
                R.drawable.trampilla,






        };

        crafteo = new int[] { R.drawable.icasco, R.drawable.ipeto,
                R.drawable.ipernera, R.drawable.ibotas,
                R.drawable.icaballo, R.drawable.ipan, R.drawable.ipastel,
                R.drawable.ipolloc,
                R.drawable.ipezc,
                R.drawable.iccerdoc,
                R.drawable.igalleta,
                R.drawable.imanzanad,
                R.drawable.izanahoriad,
                R.drawable.isopac,
                R.drawable.itartac,
                R.drawable.ifilete,
                R.drawable.ilibropluma,
                R.drawable.irelojt,
                R.drawable.ibrujula,
                R.drawable.imapa,
                R.drawable.libro,
                R.drawable.icama,
                R.drawable.ipllamas,
                R.drawable.icono,
                R.drawable.icuenco,
                R.drawable.iladrillos,
                R.drawable.icarbonv,
                R.drawable.iojoe,
                R.drawable.ilingoteo,
                R.drawable.ilingoteh,
                R.drawable.imarcoo,
                R.drawable.icuadro,
                R.drawable.ipapel,
                R.drawable.ipalo,
                R.drawable.icartel,
                R.drawable.iantorcha,
                R.drawable.iespadad,
                R.drawable.iespadao,
                R.drawable.iespadah,
                R.drawable.iespadap,
                R.drawable.iespadam,
                R.drawable.iarco,
                R.drawable.iflecha,
                R.drawable.ivagoneta,
                R.drawable.ivagonetah,
                R.drawable.ivagonetam,
                R.drawable.ibote,
                R.drawable.isillam,
                R.drawable.imtrabajo,
                R.drawable.icofre,
                R.drawable.imencantamientos,
                R.drawable.ivalla,
                R.drawable.ipvalla,
                R.drawable.ihorno,
                R.drawable.iescalera,
                R.drawable.ipicod,
                R.drawable.ihachad,
                R.drawable.ipalad,
                R.drawable.iazadad,
                R.drawable.icubo,
                R.drawable.imechero,
                R.drawable.icignea,
                R.drawable.ifcristal,
                R.drawable.icpescar,
                R.drawable.icizallas,
                R.drawable.iraild,
                R.drawable.idispensador,
                R.drawable.ipuertah,
                R.drawable.ipalanca,
                R.drawable.icajam,
                R.drawable.ipiston,
                R.drawable.ipistonp,
                R.drawable.irailp,
                R.drawable.irail,
                R.drawable.ilamparar,
                R.drawable.irepetidor,
                R.drawable.iantorchar,
                R.drawable.iboton,
                R.drawable.iplacap,
                R.drawable.itnt,
                R.drawable.ipuerta,
                R.drawable.itrampilla,






        };






        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);



        for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++)
        {
            WorldPopulation wp = new WorldPopulation(rank[i], country[i],
                    population[i], flag[i], crafteo[i]);
            // Binds all strings into an array
            arraylist.add(wp);
        }

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
        editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        // Capture Text in EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Extend `ListActivity` and override `onListItemClick()` or add a `OnListItemClickListener` to the `ListView`. Use an if statement to decide which activity to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(
    new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                TextView _countryTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countrylabel);
                Intent myIntent;
                if(_countryTextView.getText().equals("fish"))
                {
                  myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, Fish.class);
                }
                CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
             }
        }
 );
```

Define the new Activity in manifest.xml

```
 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.package.project.NextActivityName" />
```

Comment: I don't know how to put the code.. tt sorry.. mi actual code when some clicks is that i need to replace all with your answer?   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZCZ6aaOKzbyS4NKkLTpUG62FQuUKzkjMg327qZ9emKc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I change the onclick in the adapter and now works fine!! Thanks a lot! i can't vote yet.. but i put the green tick of best answer. Thaaaanks!!